# JSONArray Parsing in RecyclerView using volley android

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I am trying to parse `JSONArray` in `RecyclerView` using `volley` in `android`,  i have 10 data per page, how can I call `next page url` when we scroll down `recyclerview` every time?

My JsonArray

```
"data": {
    "total": 146,
    "per_page": 10,
    "current_page": 1,
    "last_page": 15,
    "next_page_url": "http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.com/api/v1/auth/deal?page=2",
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "from": 1,
    "to": 10,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "209",
            "ref": "101hd-209",
            "pid": "437",
            "name": "Office For Rent",
            "deal_mode": {
                "id": "128",
                "category_name": "Lease"
            },
```

My `recyclerview` load 1st page data at a time, now on scroll down how i call next `page url` to load next page data.

Comment: Simplest way is in `onBindViewHolder` check `if((list.size()==(position-1)))` if true then make callback to activity or fragment and add next page to your list in adapter.

Comment: did you make callback with `next_page_url`?

Comment: don't forget to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after adding next page to your adapter

Comment: Hello Bek, it download all data at a time, not when we scroll down recyclerview.

Comment: Hi Dinesh there is an error. I made a mistake. position+1  must be instead. This is the correct answer. `onBindViewHolder check if((list.size()==(position+1)))`

Comment: it was my mistake, i took url in for loop. but i want my recyclerview fetch next page data when we scroll down.  now how i call next `page url` to get next `page data`,

Answer (score 1):

Replace MainActivity with your activity

```
//this code will be inside adapter in onBindViewHolder
if ((position+1) == dataList.size()){
        Log.d(TAG, "equal");
        ((MainActivity) context).loadNextPage(next_page_url);
}

//this code will be in MainActivity
public void loadNextPage(String pageUrl){
    //Here you make second page request
    //And add second page to list
    //then notify your adapter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I create interface `onbottom` and check if the recyclerview is on bottom then load more data. means count will post into the API first it loaded 1st page data means count=1 then when will reach `onbottom` call function again with count++ to load second page data

Its a same structure which i faced and this helped me fine.

interface:

```
public interface OnBottomReachedListener {
    void onBottomReached(int position);

}
```

adapter:

```
OnBottomReachedListener onBottomReachedListener;
 public void setOnBottomReachedListener(OnBottomReachedListener onBottomReachedListener){

        this.onBottomReachedListener = onBottomReachedListener;
    }
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
       final PropertyInfo propertyInfo = propertyInfoList.get(position);

        if (position == propertyInfoList.size() - 1  ){

            onBottomReachedListener.onBottomReached(position);

        }
}
```

Activity:

```
adapter.setOnBottomReachedListener(new OnBottomReachedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBottomReached(int position) {
                count++;
                String URl="http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.com/api/v1/auth/deal?

                page="+count;




            }
        });
```

Comment: How can i call `next page url` when we reached bottom of `recyclerview`. that what i want.

Comment: Hello Waleed Asim, Its worked,  but problem is its reset my `recyclerview` again, i mean when i reached at bottom it load next page data but i reached at top of `recyclerview` again. every time when i reached at bottom it load next page data but throw me at top of recyclerview again and again.

Comment: @Dinesh where you call notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: where and how i call notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: just call it outside the loop if you add data in loop
youradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();